# Repeated function application in APL

Tags: apl

Given the integers *p*, *q* and *n* I would like to generate a vector of length *n* with the elements

```
(⌊p ÷ q) (⌊(⌊p ÷ q) ÷ q) ...
```

In other words I want to construct a vector where the *i*:th element is `{⌊⍵ ÷ q}` applied *i* times on *p*. How can I do that in APL?

Comment: `1↓{⍵,⌊(⊃⌽⍵)÷q}⍣n⊢p`

Comment: @ngn `⍣` seems to be a non-standard operator. Is there a portable solution?

Comment: @ngn For some reason `⊢` won't paste into Dyalog APL.

Comment: which apl implementation are you using and what do you consider standard? dyalog definitely has [`⍣`](http://help.dyalog.com/17.1/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/Power%20Operator.htm). to type `⊢` on a US keyboard, press aplkey+\ (on windows aplkey is usually ctrl).

Comment: @ngn There are two standards that I'm aware of: Core APL and Extended APL. I use both GNU APL and Dyalog APL. I think there is something wrong with my keyboard map, however, clicking the `⊢` button in the language bar works.

Comment: When asking [tag:apl] questions, it is useful to state which version of APL you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This short solution works using scan `\` works in all APLs that support even basic dfns (inline lambdas):

```apl
1↓{⌊⍵÷q}\(1+n)⍴p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///XyNPoUChUPNR2wRTBUMDBQM9C65HfVOBXMNHbZOrH/V0Perdenh7YW2MhqF2nuaj3i0F//8DAA)

Note its inefficiency; it recalculates from the beginning for every term.

A more involved solution avoids recalculation by using `/` to iterate:

```apl
r←,p
{r,←⌊(¯1↑r)÷q}/(1+n)⍴1
1↓r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///XyNPoUChUPNR2wRTBUMDBQM9C64iIEengKu6SAfIeNTTpXFoveGjtolFmoe3F9bqaxhq52k@6t1iyPWobypQAVBqctH//wA)

Comment: Thanks! If I'm not mistaken, `1 ⊃ ⌽r` can be replaced with `¯1 ↑ r`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Indeed. That's nicer.